# IIS (or the browser) is changing http to https in this code: "<script src="http://..."

Tags: javascript, iis, https

**Issue:** Code `<script src="http://...` turns to `<script src="https://...` when seen in any browser.

**Question:** how to prevent `http` turn to `https` when interpreted by IIS (or changed by the browser).
The issue is that the javascript code called won´t run when `<script src="https://...` is in place, instead of the original `<script src="http://...`. (due to certificate issues to be solved)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should fix the issue instead of forcing http

Comment: claudio tell us more for your stack. Is it .net core or .net?
Your problem does not come directly from iis, its more probable that right on the published project the conversion of the links has already been done, so it must be a build/compile step that you have that transforms them.

Comment: Could you please tell me how you find the scripts change from http to https? Form F12 develop tool network or the html element? Do you use url rewrite url or other tool to rewrite the http to https?